# Erro ResolveLibraryProjectImports no Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-forms

Boa tarde, fui compilar o APP que estou criando com Xamarin e estou tendo o seguinte erro:
Falha Inesperada da tarefa "ResolveLibraryProjectImports".
Já limpei a solução, recompilei, verifiquei conexão com o MAC, movi o projeto para um diretório mais curto, reinstalei a ferramenta e nada.
Criei um projeto novo qualquer e tudo funciona. Fiquei preocupado pois pretendo usar o Xamarin para Multiplaforma pois aqui todo setor de desenvolvimento é com C# e imagina se esse problema ficar acontecendo.
Estou com o Visual Studio COmmunity 2017 atualizado, todos os SDK's atualizados.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Esse erro é "meio genérico", tem algum outro problema específico que está gerando essa quebra de build. É meio difícil descobrir assim no escuro, tem tantos erros que podem resultar nessa mensagem.

Answer (score 0):

Comigo aconteceu este erro pq estava importando uma view de maneira errada na minha página.

Em vez de usar:

```
xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:MEUPROJETO.Views.Templates"
```

Eu estava usando:

```
x:Views="clr-namespace:SIMPASE.Views.Templates"
```

Ou seja, estava tentando importar meus controles do namespace 'x'.